# Multilingual systems and collations

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, multilingual, collation

I have come across some confusion making my system accept multiple languages.

Prior to setting up my database, I did some research as to which collation was best to use to support as many languages as possible. I was advised `utf8_unicode_ci` was the most viable encoding.

The confusion arises where, although it seems my system can decode any language, phpmyadmin cannot:

**Translation:**

```
English: 'hello'
Chinese: '你好'
```

**Encoding:**

```
System: '你好'
Phpmyadmin: 'ä½ å¥½' <------ should read: '你好'
```

How can I have phpmyadmin display these characters correctly?

Comment: Set phpmyadmin to use utf8 as well. This is a display issue.

Comment: @Shadow thanks, with help from your small nudge this link has helped me: http://superuser.com/questions/741864/how-to-display-text-in-utf8-from-mysql-phpmyadmin

Comment: You have Mokibake, probably due to declaring the table column wrong.  The data is recoverable via a 2-step ALTER; start a new question to ask how to recover.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for your input, this has actual been solved and can be closed (UTF8 all the way through problem) setting the MySQL connection to use UTF8 was the solution as pointed out by Shadow